# Why does this C code print a string from a 2D array together with the next one?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, multidimensional-array

The below code is for printing the string elements in 2D array. As the maximum length among all strings is 5, I have initialized it with max element length 5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[4][5] = {"abcde", "efghi", "ijklm", "nop"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("String: \"%s\" with length: %d\n", arr[i], (int) strlen(arr[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the result is

> String: "abcdeefghiijklmnop" with length: 18
> String: "efghiijklmnop" with length: 13
> String: "ijklmnop" with length: 8
> String: "nop" with length: 3

which is not the desired result as I want them to print separately.

Now, I change the maximum size of the string that the array *arr* can store to 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[4][6] = {"abcde", "efghi", "ijklm", "nop"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("String: \"%s\" with length: %d\n", arr[i], (int) strlen(arr[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the result now is:

> String: "abcde" with length: 5
> String: "efghi" with length: 5
> String: "ijklm" with length: 5
> String: "nop" with length: 3

Is this related to pointers somehow? Because I think the the 2D array contains pointers which are physically stored in a contiguous manner.

Comment: C strings are nul-terminated with a `'\0'` each, so you need 6 chars to store `"abcde"`.

Comment: And multi-dimensional arrays are stored contiguously in memory. That's why the unterminated strings run on into the next one.

Comment: How are you expecting `printf` to know when to stop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strings in C are actually arrays of `char` objects. Moreover, each valid string must be terminated by a char of value 0. This extra 0 byte marks the end of the string. The terminator is implicitly added to any string literal. That is why `"abcde"` consists of 6 `char`-s.

In your declaration:

```
char arr[4][5] = { "abcde", ... };
```

The string `"abcde"` is too *large* for `char[5]`, the second dimension of the array.
The terminator is ignored. As result the `"abcde"` is merged with following string as there is no terminator between them.

Now `printf("%s", arr[0])` prints the character until it finds 0-byte.
That is why you see `abcdeefghiijklmnop`. All strings got merged.

The robust fix is not using 2D array of `char` but rather an array of pointers to a constant string. Each entry in the array would be an address where the string is actually located.

```
const char *arr[4] = {"abcde", "efghi", "ijklm", "nop"};
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("String: \"%s\" with length: %d\n", arr[i], (int) strlen(arr[i]));
```

Comment: Note that with the fix array strings are no longer safely mutable. Strings stored are literals, then it would be more safe to use type `char const * arr[4]`.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking `"abcde"` does not overflow `char[5]`. There is a special rule in C that when array is initialized with literal and has no room for nul termination, it is left out automatically.

Comment: @user694733, yes. I've used a wrong wording. I meant that the terminator is truncated.